# Python function return the same value for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, pos-tagger

i want to pos-tagging a dataset of .csv file. I create a function which i hope can return the value of the pos-tagged words. But the value that return , instead give a value of the row , it return all of the value on every row. What do i miss? Is it because of the datatype or sum? anyway , here's the code that i wrote

```
def postagging(text):
pos_emotion = ct.tag_sents([df.emotion])
return pos_emotion

df['pos_emotion'] = df['emotion'].apply(postagging)
df
```

and here's the result

[image: the result]

I'm sorry if i don't explain really clear, my english is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the same value because every time you are passing `[df.emotion]` that is entire column of the dataframe instead of `text` that will be the value you want to process.

if you want to do postagging for each row you should modify your function in the following way:

```
def postagging(text):
   pos_emotion = ct.tag_sents([text])
   return pos_emotion
```

hope it helps.